# Проблемы при вставлении данных в шаблон Word. PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, ms-word, pyside2

Есть код:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QLabel
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *

from docxtpl import DocxTemplate


class Widget(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        uic.loadUi("test2.ui", self)
        # Добавить/удалить строку в tableWidget_2
        #self.pushButton_7.clicked.connect(self.buttonAdd)
        #self.pushButton_8.clicked.connect(self.buttonDelete)
        # Добавить/удалить строку в tableWidget_3
        self.pushButton_9.clicked.connect(self.buttonAdd_2)
        self.pushButton_10.clicked.connect(self.buttonDelete_2)
        # Сохранить данные из таблицы tableWidget_3
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.buttonSave)

        for row in range(self.tableWidget_3.rowCount()):
            date_from = QtWidgets.QDateTimeEdit()
            date_from.setDateTime(
                QtCore.QDateTime(QtCore.QDate(2021, 8, 26),
                                 QtCore.QTime(15, 0, 0))
            )
            self.tableWidget_3.setCellWidget(row, 0, date_from)

        for row in range(self.tableWidget_3.rowCount()):
            date_from = QDateTimeEdit()
            date_from.setDateTime(
                QDateTime(QDate(2021, 9, 2))
            )
            date_from.dateTimeChanged.connect(
                lambda dateTime, row=row: self.date_changed(dateTime, row))
            self.tableWidget_3.setCellWidget(row, 0, date_from)

        self.dateTime0 = self.tableWidget_3.cellWidget(0, 0).dateTime()

    # Расчет времени от начального значения
    def date_changed(self, dateTime, row):
        if row == 0:
            self.dateTime0 = self.tableWidget_3.cellWidget(row, 0).dateTime()
            for row in range(1, self.tableWidget_3.rowCount()):
                dateTime2 = self.tableWidget_3.cellWidget(row, 0).dateTime()
                item = QTableWidgetItem()
                item.setData(Qt.DisplayRole,
                             self.dateTime0.secsTo(dateTime2) / 60. / 60.)
                self.tableWidget_3.setItem(row, 1, item)
            return

        dateTime2 = self.tableWidget_3.cellWidget(row, 0).dateTime()
        item = QTableWidgetItem()
        item.setData(Qt.DisplayRole,
                     self.dateTime0.secsTo(dateTime2) / 60. / 60.)
        self.tableWidget_3.setItem(row, 1, item)

    # Кнопка дабовляющая строку в таблицу tableWidget_2
    def buttonAdd(self):
        rowPosition = self.tableWidget_2.rowCount()
        self.tableWidget_2.insertRow(rowPosition)

    # Кнопка удаляющая строку в таблицу tableWidget_2
    def buttonDelete(self):
        if self.tableWidget_2.rowCount() > 0:
            self.tableWidget_2.removeRow(self.tableWidget_2.rowCount()-1)

    # Кнопка дабовляющая строку в таблицу tableWidget_3
    def buttonAdd_2(self):
        rowPosition = self.tableWidget_3.rowCount()
        self.tableWidget_3.insertRow(rowPosition)
        date_from = QtWidgets.QDateTimeEdit()
        dateTime = QtCore.QDateTime().currentDateTime()
        date_from.setDateTime(dateTime)
        date_from.dateTimeChanged.connect(
            lambda dateTime, row=rowPosition:
            self.date_changed(dateTime, row))
        self.tableWidget_3.setCellWidget(rowPosition, 0, date_from)

    # Кнопка удаляющая строку в таблицу tableWidget_3
    def buttonDelete_2(self):
        if self.tableWidget_3.rowCount() > 0:
            self.tableWidget_3.removeRow(self.tableWidget_3.rowCount() - 1)

    # Сохранение данных из tableWidget_3
    def buttonSave(self):
        rows = self.tableWidget_3.rowCount()
        cols = self.tableWidget_3.columnCount()

        data_for_word = []
        for row in range(rows):
            tmp = []
            for col in range(cols):
                if col:
                    item = self.tableWidget_3.item(row, col)
                    item = item.text() if item else 'No data'
                else:
                    #             dateTime
                    #               vvvv
                    item = self.tableWidget_3.cellWidget(row, 0). \
                        dateTime().toString('dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm')
                tmp.append(item)

            data_for_word.append(tmp)

        for i in data_for_word: print(i)

        self.buttonLoader()


    # Загрузка данных в шаблон Word
    def buttonLoader(self):
        rows = self.tableWidget_3.rowCount()
        cols = self.tableWidget_3.columnCount()
        data = []
        for row in range(rows):
            tmp = []
            for col in range(cols):
                try:
                    tmp.append(self.tableWidget_3.item(row, col).text())
                except:
                    tmp.append('')
            data.append(tmp)

        data_for_word = []
        # for i in data: print(i)

        for i in data:
            if i[0] != '':
                data_for_word.append(i)

        data_for_word = []

        for item in data:
            if any(item):
                data_for_word.append({
                    "data": item[0],
                    "time": item[1],
                    "ph": item[2],
                    "ph2": item[3],
                    "fe": item[4],
                    "pm": item[5],
                    "co2": item[6],
                    "pm2": item[7],
                    "pm3": item[8]
                })

        doc = DocxTemplate('test_word.docx')  # Загрузить шаблон (создать новый документ по шаблону)

        context = {
            'tbl_contents': data_for_word
        }

        doc.render(context)  # Заполнить шаблон по данным из context

        doc.save('test2.docx')  # Сохранить в новый файл


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Widget()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Данный код должен собирать данные из таблицы (`tableWidget_3`), после чего вставлять эти данные по шаблону в **`word`**. 
Но, при заполнении таблицы в шаблон возникает проблема:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В первом столбце должны находится данные но, их нет.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В первом столбце есть `dataEdit` из которого данные должны собираться и вставляется в шаблон.

[image: Шаблон word]

Код **ui**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>640</width>
    <height>480</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
    <item row="2" column="0">
     <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
      <item>
       <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_10">
        <property name="text">
         <string>Удалить</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item>
       <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_9">
        <property name="text">
         <string>Добавить</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
     </layout>
    </item>
    <item row="0" column="0">
     <widget class="QTableWidget" name="tableWidget_3">
      <row>
       <property name="text">
        <string>New Row</string>
       </property>
      </row>
      <column>
       <property name="text">
        <string>1</string>
       </property>
      </column>
      <column>
       <property name="text">
        <string>2</string>
       </property>
      </column>
      <column>
       <property name="text">
        <string>3</string>
       </property>
      </column>
      <column>
       <property name="text">
        <string>4</string>
       </property>
      </column>
      <column>
       <property name="text">
        <string>5</string>
       </property>
      </column>
      <column>
       <property name="text">
        <string>6</string>
       </property>
      </column>
      <column>
       <property name="text">
        <string>7</string>
       </property>
      </column>
      <column>
       <property name="text">
        <string>8</string>
       </property>
      </column>
      <column>
       <property name="text">
        <string>9</string>
       </property>
      </column>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item row="1" column="0">
     <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
      <property name="text">
       <string>Считать данные</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>640</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Как решить данную проблему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте заменить

```
...

    # Сохранение данных из tableWidget_3
    def buttonSave(self):
        rows = self.tableWidget_3.rowCount()
        cols = self.tableWidget_3.columnCount()

        data_for_word = []
        for row in range(rows):
            tmp = []
            for col in range(cols):
                if col:
                    item = self.tableWidget_3.item(row, col)
# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
                    if col == 1:
                        item = f'{float(item.text()):.2f}' if item else 'No data'
                    else:     
                        item = item.text() if item else 'No data'
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                else:
                    item = self.tableWidget_3.cellWidget(row, 0). \
                        dateTime().toString('dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm')
                tmp.append(item)

            data_for_word.append(tmp)

        for i in data_for_word: print(i)

        self.buttonLoader(data_for_word)          # +++ data_for_word  

    # Загрузка данных в шаблон Word
    def buttonLoader(self, data):                 # +++ data 
    
        ''' !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Вы это уже сделали выше !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        
        rows = self.tableWidget_3.rowCount()
        cols = self.tableWidget_3.columnCount()
        data = []
        for row in range(rows):
            tmp = []
            for col in range(cols):
                try:
                    tmp.append(self.tableWidget_3.item(row, col).text())
                except:
                    tmp.append('')
            data.append(tmp)
        data_for_word = []
        # for i in data: print(i)
        for i in data:
            if i[0] != '':
                data_for_word.append(i)
        '''

        data_for_word = []

        for item in data:
            if any(item):
                data_for_word.append({
                    "data": item[0],
                    "time": item[1],
                    "ph": item[2],
                    "ph2": item[3],
                    "fe": item[4],
                    "pm": item[5],
                    "co2": item[6],
                    "pm2": item[7],
                    "pm3": item[8]
                })
                
        for i in data_for_word: print(i)
        
        doc = DocxTemplate('test_word.docx')  
        context = {
            'tbl_contents': data_for_word
        }
        doc.render(context)     # Заполнить шаблон по данным из context
        doc.save('test2.docx')  # Сохранить в новый файл

...
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Полный текст **main.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QLabel
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *

from docxtpl import DocxTemplate


class Widget(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        uic.loadUi("test2.ui", self)
        # Добавить/удалить строку в tableWidget_2
        #self.pushButton_7.clicked.connect(self.buttonAdd)
        #self.pushButton_8.clicked.connect(self.buttonDelete)
        # Добавить/удалить строку в tableWidget_3
        self.pushButton_9.clicked.connect(self.buttonAdd_2)
        self.pushButton_10.clicked.connect(self.buttonDelete_2)
        # Сохранить данные из таблицы tableWidget_3
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.buttonSave)

        for row in range(self.tableWidget_3.rowCount()):
            date_from = QtWidgets.QDateTimeEdit()
            date_from.setDateTime(
                QtCore.QDateTime(QtCore.QDate(2021, 8, 26),
                                 QtCore.QTime(15, 0, 0))
            )
            self.tableWidget_3.setCellWidget(row, 0, date_from)

        for row in range(self.tableWidget_3.rowCount()):
            date_from = QDateTimeEdit()
            date_from.setDateTime(
                QDateTime(QDate(2021, 9, 2))
            )
            date_from.dateTimeChanged.connect(
                lambda dateTime, row=row: self.date_changed(dateTime, row))
            self.tableWidget_3.setCellWidget(row, 0, date_from)

        self.dateTime0 = self.tableWidget_3.cellWidget(0, 0).dateTime()

    # Расчет времени от начального значения
    def date_changed(self, dateTime, row):
        if row == 0:
            self.dateTime0 = self.tableWidget_3.cellWidget(row, 0).dateTime()
            for row in range(1, self.tableWidget_3.rowCount()):
                dateTime2 = self.tableWidget_3.cellWidget(row, 0).dateTime()
                item = QTableWidgetItem()
                item.setData(Qt.DisplayRole,
                             self.dateTime0.secsTo(dateTime2) / 60. / 60.)
                self.tableWidget_3.setItem(row, 1, item)
            return

        dateTime2 = self.tableWidget_3.cellWidget(row, 0).dateTime()
        item = QTableWidgetItem()
        item.setData(Qt.DisplayRole,
                     self.dateTime0.secsTo(dateTime2) / 60. / 60.)
        self.tableWidget_3.setItem(row, 1, item)

    # Кнопка дабовляющая строку в таблицу tableWidget_2
    def buttonAdd(self):
        rowPosition = self.tableWidget_2.rowCount()
        self.tableWidget_2.insertRow(rowPosition)

    # Кнопка удаляющая строку в таблицу tableWidget_2
    def buttonDelete(self):
        if self.tableWidget_2.rowCount() > 0:
            self.tableWidget_2.removeRow(self.tableWidget_2.rowCount()-1)

    # Кнопка дабовляющая строку в таблицу tableWidget_3
    def buttonAdd_2(self):
        rowPosition = self.tableWidget_3.rowCount()
        self.tableWidget_3.insertRow(rowPosition)
        date_from = QtWidgets.QDateTimeEdit()
        dateTime = QtCore.QDateTime().currentDateTime()
        date_from.setDateTime(dateTime)
        date_from.dateTimeChanged.connect(
            lambda dateTime, row=rowPosition:
            self.date_changed(dateTime, row))
        self.tableWidget_3.setCellWidget(rowPosition, 0, date_from)

    # Кнопка удаляющая строку в таблицу tableWidget_3
    def buttonDelete_2(self):
        if self.tableWidget_3.rowCount() > 0:
            self.tableWidget_3.removeRow(self.tableWidget_3.rowCount() - 1)

    # Сохранение данных из tableWidget_3
    def buttonSave(self):
        rows = self.tableWidget_3.rowCount()
        cols = self.tableWidget_3.columnCount()

        data_for_word = []
        for row in range(rows):
            tmp = []
            for col in range(cols):
                if col:
                    item = self.tableWidget_3.item(row, col)
# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
                    if col == 1:
                        item = f'{float(item.text()):.2f}' if item else 'No data'
                    else:     
                        item = item.text() if item else 'No data'
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                else:
                    item = self.tableWidget_3.cellWidget(row, 0). \
                        dateTime().toString('dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm')
                tmp.append(item)

            data_for_word.append(tmp)

        for i in data_for_word: print(i)

        self.buttonLoader(data_for_word)          # +++ data_for_word  

    # Загрузка данных в шаблон Word
    def buttonLoader(self, data):                 # +++ data 
    
        ''' !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Вы это уже сделали выше !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        
        rows = self.tableWidget_3.rowCount()
        cols = self.tableWidget_3.columnCount()
        data = []
        for row in range(rows):
            tmp = []
            for col in range(cols):
                try:
                    tmp.append(self.tableWidget_3.item(row, col).text())
                except:
                    tmp.append('')
            data.append(tmp)
        data_for_word = []
        # for i in data: print(i)
        for i in data:
            if i[0] != '':
                data_for_word.append(i)
        '''

        data_for_word = []

        for item in data:
            if any(item):
                data_for_word.append({
                    "data": item[0],
                    "time": item[1],
                    "ph": item[2],
                    "ph2": item[3],
                    "fe": item[4],
                    "pm": item[5],
                    "co2": item[6],
                    "pm2": item[7],
                    "pm3": item[8]
                })
        
        print()        
        for i in data_for_word: print(i)
        
        doc = DocxTemplate('test_word.docx')  
        context = {
            'tbl_contents': data_for_word
        }
        doc.render(context)     # Заполнить шаблон по данным из context
        doc.save('test2.docx')  # Сохранить в новый файл


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Widget()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: не помогло данные точно также вставляются без dataEdit и округления второго столбца.

Comment: @АндрейАлександров я всегда проверяю свои ответы, а если не проверяю, то пишу что не проверено. Данные сформированы так как вам надо. Я не могу проверить вашу вставку в 'test2.docx', так как я вам уже писал ранее. что для этого вы должны как-то поделится 'test_word.docx'.

Comment: @АндрейАлександров проверьте еще раз.

Comment: нашел ошибку, теперь все работает!

Comment: только данные во втором столбце не округляются до целых.

Comment: @АндрейАлександров замените строку `item = f'{float(item.text()):.2f}' if item else 'No data'` на `item = f'{float(item.text()):.0f}' if item else 'No data'`